# Was Light actually a friend to L?

Tags: death-note

I know L said Light was his first friend but did he mean it? Yes we know L is a liar and knew Light was Kira the whole time but what if, during the time Light lost his memories, L thought of Light as a genuine friend. It’s all very confusing to me still so can someone answer?

Comment: Related from the opposite PoV: [Did Light actually like L (in a friendship way)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21482/2516)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, no.

So here's the thing, the author of *Death Note*, Tsugumi Ohba put little notes and other trivia in *Death Note 13: How to Read*. And some even asked if L was genuine about him being friends with Kira. To which he answered "No" as L was lying to catch Kira.

From [page 64 of the English translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYseWl.png):

> **L Has No Friends?**
>
> Nope. And when he says that Light is his first friend that's a big lie. He never considers him a friend. He probably secretly thinks really negative things about him.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Yes.
**L** considered him as a friend because they had a lot of coherence as compared to the other characters even if he had a strong suspicion on Light being KIRA.

Also, to the "What if part" : he was never 100 % sure, but had a strong suspicion on Light.

Answer (score 0):

L did have emotions but Light not.

L really considered Light as a friend, but at the same time was sure that Light was Kira. We can see that when L was dying (ep. 25), L was regretting that he is sure that Light is Kira, but has no way to prove it. So he still showed gratitude to Kira, and wiped his feet.